# Format a Date into Mai 2010 in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, datetime, format

how do I format a date (smalldatetime) in Mai 2010 (i.e. 06.05.2010 => Mai 2010 or 06.10.2009 => October 2009)

thx a lot... greetings

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Format a SmallDateTime to a specific culture date (which one?)? Convert a string to a SmallDateTime? If you post some code, we can understand better what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to group varios dates (mm.dd.yyyy) into month year (Monthname Year)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 107), 0, 4) + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 107), 8, 5)
```

Changing `GETDATE()` with your column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CONVERT function to convert it to a string, the function can take an optional 3d parameter called style that takes an integer determining the formatting.

more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)